# How to create a listing with sorting searching component in Vuejs 2 and bootstrap 3 + laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm new in vuejs so anyone can explain the how to create a listing( for example User, My Order like grid) components.

I have found one best solution but this is not compatible in bootstrap-3, but my existing project is under the bootstrap-3

I want similar to this in bootstrap3:
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#complete-example

Is there any bootstap-vue version is compatible in bootstap3 if no then can you please give a alternate solution.

Thank in advance.

Comment: take a look at this https://uiv.wxsm.space

Comment: Yes i have visited this package but i don't see any grid demo anywhere, if you know any available demo for reference then please provide the same.

Comment: https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue2-bootstrap-table seems like table you wanted

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://ratiw.github.io/vuetable-2
The component is highly modifiable, and you can pass objects with classes in his props to make the table work with with every css framework:

template:

```
<vuetable ref="movementsTable"
           :css="table"
           api-url="api/movements/resource"
           :fields="fields"
           pagination-path=""
           ></vuetable>
```

state:

```
data() {
  return {
    table: {
      tableClass: 'table table-hover',
      loadingClass: 'loading',
      ascendingIcon: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
      descendingIcon: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
      handleIcon: 'fa fa-caret-left',
    },
  },
},
```

Check this example! https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-with-laravel-5.4